# How do the HortonWorks and MAPR VMs receive connections on localhost?

Tags: tcp, virtualbox, localhost

I just downloaded both the Hortonworks and the MAPR VMs for VirtualBox. Both of them start up VirtualBox and then give a UI that looks like this:

[image]

What I don't understand is this: how do the VMs, running on another "virtual" machine, accept TCP connections to localhost? Localhost is the IP address of the host computer, not the guest VM. So how do they accept the TCP connections?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer, and it's embarrassingly obvious. It turns out that port forwarding is set up in the VM, and the forwarding is bi-directional.

[image]